# Why does my program freeze in the middle of a pipe read?

Tags: c++, pipe

I'm writing a C++ program for class that requires a set of N child processes to communicate with their parent process on a Unix-based system. To that end, I declared two arrays of N pipes, one for each direction of communication, before forking the process:

```
int pipesToParent[N][2];
int pipesToChild[N][2];

... // for int i = 0 to N-1, pipe(pipesToParent[i]), pipe(pipesToChild[i]),
    // fork(), yada yada, I included error checking and everything.

int pipesToChild[N][2];
```

Most of the code for the parent process is in a while loop; near the beginning of this loop, it reads a message from a particular process:

```
read(pipesToParent[processToServe][READ_END], charArray, BUF_SIZE);
```

The first time it goes through the loop, reading a message from process X, it works fine. Then it's instructed to do the same for process Y, the message from which contains exactly the same sort of data as process X (I have each process cout its message when it writes it to its pipe), and the process just stops. It doesn't exit, it just stays frozen at that line. I've tried everything I can think of to figure out what might be wrong with the message I'm sending, but it all looks just fine. What's going on here?

(Sorry if my detail's insufficient; I couldn't figure out what else I'd have to include and what I could remove to paste something that'd reproduce the problem.)

**ETA:**

The child process has its own internal while loop, in which it reads from its own pipe:

```
read(pipesToChild[thisProcessNumber][READ_END], charArray, BUF_SIZE);
```

If the parent's ready, it'll send its message:

```
write(pipesToParent[thisProcessNumber][WRITE_END], message, BUF_SIZE);
```

Some tinkering has revealed that process Y, much like the parent, is going through this loop once fine, then getting stuck on the read the second time. What exactly would flushing do, and can I do it if I wrote to/read from the pipe this way? (If it's relevant, I've #included cstdlib, but not cstdio.)

Comment: Either you didn't set up your plumbing correctly, process Y didn't actually write the data, or you've got a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), or something else is wrong. It's hard to know for sure without more code.

Comment: It could be the process Y isn't writing a message to the pipe for some reason.  The process reading from the pipe will block while it waits for data to show up in the pipe.  I would make sure that Y is really writing to the pipe.

Comment: From man page, "Note that output popen() streams are fully buffered by default."  Do you fflush() after writing?

Comment: I'm suspicious about the design in C++ that uses arrays like that.  You should probably think in terms of each process having a structure associated with it that contains the relevant pipe information, and then using arrays of that structure.  Unless it is too early in your C++ course to be using structures/classes, but then one wonders how they are teaching you.

Comment: Since we can't see how you're setting up the children, and whether you're closing enough file descriptors, it is going to hard to diagnose your problem by remote control.  The freeze might be because your parent process is reading from a file descriptor that is open, but that is not the one on which Y has written its data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's an operating systems course, not a C++ course. I haven't written any classes of my own for this, which I'm sure is terrible practice -- it's been ages since I really did much with OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like deadlock to me - both your processes are waiting for another one to 
write something - but none of them actually writes anything, so everything stops. Make sure that your comunication design is deadlock-free (eg. clients reding conantly and writing only on reading READY comunicate, and server reading only fter writing READ comunicate). You might also consider going to non-blocking pipes.

As far as i know pipes created with pipe() call are unbuffered - the only buffer involved is pipe buffer, but as this is the same buffer from which reading in target app is done, it cannot create comunnication problems. Application-level happens only if you map file descriptors to C-like FILE pointers, but it seems it's not the case.

If you still think that everything is ok, post minimal compilable code that shows this behavior, so I can perhaps say more.

EDIT:

Since you accepted an answer, it would be nice if you mentioned also which solution (if any) solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond until this late. Turned out I was reading one ifstream at a point that was screwing up other things. I found a different way to do the checking the program was doing at that point and the problem cleared up. (Sorry if that's confusing. -_-)